# Parametros na Query

Tags: c#, sql, winforms

Ao montar uma Query usando AddWithValue. Mesmo estando certo, o retorno não é o esperado.

No exemplo abaixo o retorno é Zero

```
var query = "SELECT nome,usuario,email,administrador FROM GSCUsuarios WHERE @parametroWhere = @parametroCondicao");

dataAdapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("parametroWhere", parametroWhere);
dataAdapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("parametroCondicao", parametroCondicao);
```

Resolvi perguntar no stackoverflow americano e foi sugerido trocar a query para o seguinte formato

```
var query = string.Format("SELECT nome,usuario,email,administrador FROM GSCUsuarios WHERE {0} = @parametroCondicao", parametroWhere);

dataAdapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("parametroCondicao", parametroCondicao);
```

O que eu gostaria de entender é porque da primeira Query não ter funcionado. O AddWithValue não apenas trocou os valores?

Fazendo outra Query, usando LIKE.. também não funcionou!
Como deveria ser montado esta Query?

```
var query = string.Format("SELECT nome,usuario,email,administrador FROM GSCUsuarios WHERE {0} LIKE '@parametroCondicao%'", parametroWhere);

dataAdapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("parametroCondicao", parametroCondicao);
```

Obrigado

Comment: Veja que teu parametroWhere está = parametroCondicao, isso vai depender de como você está executando isso

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O porque da primeira query não funcionar: parâmetros para queries do SQL são interpretados de acordo com o seu valor; um parâmetro do tipo string será convertido para uma string na query (*). A sua primeira query é equivalente a:

```
SELECT nome,usuario,email,administrador
FROM GSCUsuarios
WHERE 'valorDoParametroWhere' = 'valorDoParametroCondicao'
```

E como a condição `WHERE` nunca vai ser verdadeira (a não ser no caso do valor da coluna ser igual ao nome da coluna), você sempre terá 0 resultados.

Em relação ao uso do `LIKE`, você pode usar o seguinte:

```
var query = string.Format(@"SELECT nome,usuario,email,administrador
                            FROM GSCUsuarios
                            WHERE {0} LIKE @parametroCondicao",
    parametroWhere);

dataAdapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue(
    "parametroCondicao",
    parametroCondicao + "%");
```

Note que o uso de `string.Format` para criar comandos SQL é perigoso - só faça isso se você tiver absoluta certeza que o valor de `parametroWhere` não vem diretamente do usuário (ou você estárá sujeito a [ataques de injeção de SQL](http://xkcd.com/327/))

(*) Na verdade a query é compilada antes da aplicação dos parâmetros, mas a ideia é a mesma.

Comment: CarlosFigueira, muito obrigado. Agora ficou bem esclarecido.
a variavel parametroWhere vem de um ComboBox, então creio que seja seguro. 
Fiz as modificações que sugeriu e a Query Like funcionou, valeu mesmo.

Comment: Note que a variável `parametroWhere` pode vir de um combobox, mas na rede ela vai como uma string. Se um hacker quiser *bypass* o seu formulário, ele/ela pode mandar a requisição direto pela rede (usando algo tipo Postman ou Fiddler), então você não pode confiar no valor que veio do cliente.

Comment: Carlos, o meu projeto é uma Aplicação WinForms.. posso ter este tipo de problemas também?

Comment: Se a aplicação não envia nenhum dado pela rede (i.e., o acesso ao BD é local), então você não tem problema. Se um hacker estiver acessando a sua aplicação no computador, então há formas bem mais fáceis de se causar danos (e.g., `echo y | format c:`) que você não precisa se preocupar com as mais complicadas.